# Is there a good flag icon pack that corresponds to ISO-3166 Country Codes?

Tags: internationalization, icons, country-codes, iso-3166

I'm in need of an icon pack containing flags that correspond with [ISO-3166 country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm) such as **US**, **CA**, **SE**, **DE** etc. Optimally the flag icons would have names such as **us.png**, **ca.png** and so on. I'm guessing this is a common developer necessity making this a great place to ask.

Comment: "I need some icons" really isn't a question, much less a good one for Stack Overflow. [Even so...](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/)

Comment: Reformatted title to question form, and thanks for the link

Comment: agree, it's not really a SO question — but i am as well searching for an FlagIcons-as-a-Service hotlinking service with https..... famfamfam is oldish, not really retina style etc....

Comment: All flags in SVG and optimised for web.. https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css

Comment: I've flagged this for re-open. To me, it fits "software tools commonly used by programmers" (fora  fairly general meaning of "tool") and "is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" of the [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) stack overflow guide.

Comment: GitHub hosted:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/behdad/region-flags/gh-pages/png/IE.png

Use ISO two letter country ID as image name.

Comment: I am using https://www.flag-sprites.com/ and I love them

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/

Also have a look at:

- http://icondrawer.com/free.php
- https://www.gosquared.com/resources/flag-icons
- http://www.content-pack.com/free-flags-icons/
- https://github.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon
- http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2016/10/list-of-country-flags-png-by-iso3.html
- https://dribbble.com/shots/1089488-Stripe-Flag-Set

Comment: Pretty much, but the icons are very small

Comment: Well what size are you looking for it would be helpful to know.

Comment: Was waiting for you to edit in the awesome icon packs :P

Comment: A recent and quite nice addition to country flag icons sets: https://www.gosquared.com/resources/flag-icons. From 16x16 to 64x64 and also not that glossy as the icon-draw versions. It also coverts 250 countries.

Comment: @antitoxic under what conditions can i use the https://www.gosquared.com/resources/flag-icons/ flags in my android app? In the dowloaded flag pack in the file LICENSE.txt i found this sentence: "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.". Does it mean that I have to copy the file contents somewhere in my apps?

Comment: Another set is http://www.content-pack.com/free-flags-icons/ . But I don't understand if I can use the set in the app or not... :(

Comment: @zatziky i don't know. I have no affiliation with the icon pack. I simply found it, i never used it.

Comment: This is an excellent pack with svg that can be converted to large png: https://github.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon

Comment: country flags | PNG | ISO3 | 3 letter country name -> http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2016/10/list-of-country-flags-png-by-iso3.html   (OPEN SOURCE)

Comment: Another super cool set of country flags developed/used by the popular payment processor Stripe and free are these: https://dribbble.com/shots/1089488-Stripe-Flag-Set They are only 100 so won't cover all countries.

Comment: https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags

Comment: @P.Galbraith Your last link (365icon.com) now points to a spam/phishing site, please edit your answer

Comment: @Hubro thanks I've removed that link now.